# How to retrieve Ids of a collection of objects after savechanges from database using Entity Framework code first

Tags: c#, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6

I have a method to add a collection of objects to database using code first.
Here collection is added using `AddRange` method. But I need Ids (primary keys)
of each added object from database. Here primary key is numeric and auto incremented. How it retrieve it?

Thanks

```
private bool CaseTaskMapping(long workFlowId,long caseDetailId)
{
    if (workFlowId > 0)
    {
        try
        {
            var StateList = dbContext.States.Where(state => state.WorkflowId == workFlowId);
           List<CaseTaskMapping> CaseTaskMappingList = new List<CaseTaskMapping>();

           foreach (var state in StateList)
           {
               var TaskList = dbContext.Tasks.Where(task => task.StateId == state.StateId);                   

               foreach (var tasks in TaskList)
               {
                   CaseTaskMappingList.Add(new CaseTaskMapping
                        {
                            CaseDetailsId = caseDetailId,
                            TaskId = tasks.TaskId,
                            IsComplete = false,
                            LastUpdatedBy = GetLoggedUserId(),
                            LastUpdatedOn = DateTime.Now
                        });
               }
           }

           dbContext.CaseTaskMappings.AddRange(CaseTaskMappingList);
           dbContext.SaveChanges();

           // Here I need Ids of the above collection save to the database
           return true;
       }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Entity Framework is going to automatically populate the Primary Keys on the newly added objects after `SaveChanges` is called.

Since you already have references to all the objects that are being added in a variable named `CaseTaskMappingList`, you can simply use that same variable to get the new Ids after `SaveChanges` operation.

```
var insertedKeys = CaseTaskMappingList.Select(x => x.Id); // assuming that Id is the name of Primary Key
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply